# How to unsubscribe with useEffect with a function return from a promise?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I call a promise, it returns a unsubscribe function. How do I unsubscribe it with the return function in `useEffect`?

```js
useEffect(()=>{
   let unSub = ()=>{}   

   async function run(){
        unSub = await promise();
   }

   run();

   
   return unSub
})
```

Thinking something like this, do not know if it is the correct way, what's the react way of doing it?

Comment: i don't find anything wrong in it..

Comment: Just wondering, since the run() is not async, what about when cleaning up, the unSub has been assigned so it is just an empty function, which make the unsubscribe failed, could it be the case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a specific well-known practice for your specific case. Traditional React way of unsubscribing from `async` actions is using a boolean in the main body of the `useEffect`, and resetting it in the cleanup.

If you're using the `fetch` api, the `AbortController` api can cancel requests. If you're using axios, there are things called `cancelTokens` that can cancel requests.

Perhaps this can be a solution:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    let unSub = ()=>{};
    let isMounted   = true;
    let newUnSubSet = false;
    async function run(){
         unSub = await promise();
         newUnSubSet = true;
    }
     
    run();
     
    
    return () => {
        if (newUnSubSet) {
            unSub();
        }
        newUnSubSet = false;
        isMounted = false;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(()=>{
   let unSub;   

   async function run(){
        unSub = await promise();
   }

   run();

   
   return ()=> unSub && unSub();
})
```

Or basic Pub/Sub pattern:

```
useEffect(()=>{
   let handlers= [];   

   async function run(){
        unSub = await promise();
        handlers.push(unSub);
   }

   run();

   
   return ()=> handlers.forEach(handler=> handler());
})
```

Answer (score -2):

```
// on component mount
useEffect(() => {
    // do some stuff ie. subscribe

    // on component unmount
    return () => {
       // do some stuff ie. unsubscribe
    }
}, [/* dependencies */])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know the pattern of clean up, and already doing that, my question is the unsubscribe function is returned from a promise, how to ensure it is executed when unmount, is the code I provide follows the practice?